# Best way to find latest Feed posted

Tags: php, rss, feed

Can any one please let me know, that i need to receive feeds which are posted recently

OR

```
Please make sure if the feed is posted, should it be shown in the first position?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://reader.google.com